# How do I save a file in python since the url contain "?" caracter?

Tags: python-3.x, queue, python-requests, python-multithreading

I am still learning. Maybe this question is very simple and easy to some, but I am breaking my head tryng to solve this small problem. I am running a multi-threading and queue to download .HTML files from a site. Ok. Everything is working great, exept when I try to save the file. Once the URL contain special caracters, (this one -> "?"), I am not being able to save the file... special caracter are note allowed to use when saving a file (/:?*<>), right ??

the urls is this one. It is a html file when I load this with my user name and password.

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    urls = ["https://supercarros.com.br/Carros?codigoUC=17342856", "https://supercarros.com.br/Carros?codigoUC=3707466"]
    main(urls)
```

when I try to save using this part of the code:

```
def download_file(self, url): 
    handle = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    fname = os.path.basename(url + ".htm")
        with open(fname, "wb") as f:
            for chunk in handle.iter_content(chunk_size=1024):
                if chunk:
                    f.write(chunk)
            del handle
```

i get this return:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python3\lib\threading.py", line 916, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "f.py", line 24, in run
    self.download_file(url)
  File "f.py", line 33, in download_file
    with open(fname, "wb") as f:
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'Carros?codigoUC=17342856.htm'

Exception in thread Thread-2:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python3\lib\threading.py", line 916, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "f.py", line 24, in run
    self.download_file(url)
  File "f.py", line 33, in download_file
    with open(fname, "wb") as f:
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'Carros?codigoUC=3707466.htm'
```

Of course... it will not allow me. 
 My question is.. how do I solve this small issue ?? what should I do to save the file without the "?" caracter, but keeping the last part "codigoUC=3707466.htm"

All help is appreciated.
 Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to remove the `?` character from the name, you can do:

```
with open(fname.replace('?', ''), "wb") as f:
```

And the name of the file would end up being `CarroscodigoUC=17342856.htm`

If you want to delete all the special characters, you can use a regular expression:

```
import re
fname = re.sub(r'[/:?*<>]', r'', fname)
```

Comment: awesome !! both ways worked !! the last one is the best !! Thank you very much for taking your sunday to help me !!

Comment: can you help me with another question ?? in this same code. instead of putting a lot urls, which take a long time to put one per one... how can I make this load a .txt list with all urls??

Comment: Take a look at the [python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files) regarding reading files, you can use that as a starting point

Comment: I use this for now, if __name__ == "__main__":
    urls = ["https://supercarros.com.br/Carros?codigoUC=17342856", "https://supercarros.com.br/Carros?codigoUC=3707466"]
    main(urls)... But it take a long time to put the urls. So, I tried to substitute for try:
    for url in open('url.txt'):
        q.put(url.strip())
    q.join()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    sys.exit(1).. but it is not working

Comment: It's hard to debug without more info, consider creating a different question to avoid having a long discussion in the comments

Comment: you are right !! Thank you !! I hope you can help me there !